# How can I send a JS file along with HTML and CSS with Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

All I want to do is test if I can actually send a js file alongside my CSS and HTML files(which they did successfully send).

I'm new to express so I just want to know how to do this, I tried searching around and didn't find a solution after trying some.

Here is file structure:
PROJECT

Project name

- public

  - js (js file here)
  - css (css file here)
- views (html here)
- app.js

Here is my express code:

```
import express from "express";
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import { dirname } from 'path';

const port = 3000;
const app = express();
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = dirname(__filename);

app.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`)
})

app.use(express.static('public'));

// Send the first html file
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/views/index.html");
})
```